# Benchmarking Matrix Multiplication on Android, C++

Tags: android, memory, matrix, linear-algebra

Hi I'm using Android with JNI (Java - C++) to benchmark some matrix multiplication operations on Android Devices. Does anyone have any resources on tests that have previously been conducted? I'm sure this is a well visited problem and would like to see what's already been done out there. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use, [Linpack Benchmark Suite,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LINPACK_benchmarks) which is designed for CPU benchmarks by using matrix operations.  You may also check [the 0xbench,](http://code.google.com/p/0xbench/wiki/Benchmarks) an open source benchmark suite for android, for the source code of the Linkack Benchmark